# Magento order import/export

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there any way to import/export the orders from magento. Since we have magento store on live and another dev. version is ready with greatest change now we only need to import the magento orders alone. Here i can see only export -

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/slandsbek/extension/1350/simple-order-export

But how can i import the order data into new store.

Comment: Not really a programming question... We really need that Magento site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-dataflow-batch-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

It's $99 but there's no simple answer to your problem.  If you're not willing to pay for an extension, then unfortunately you'll have to write some code to do this yourself.

Comment: I purchased this app and it has yet to import a single order for me in Magento 1.5. I am still working with the developer to get it working but I can tell you that even if you get this module working it is a bit limited as far as I can tell. For example it seems you have to set the payment processor to 'purchase order' to do an import regardless of what the actual payment method was.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/savajr/extension/1822/store-manager-for-magento  -- it's $199, i mean, really you just gotta look around in magento connect... nobody is going to give you a magic bullet here, it's not an extremely simple here's a few snips of code solution.

Comment: It is not working from CE1.6 to CE 1.9

Answer (score 2):

For orders exportation you could try this module : Orders export tool from Wyomind.
It's a "Data feed manager like" but for orders : 
[Orders export tool](http://www.wyomind.com/orders-export-tool-magento.html)
[Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/15714/)
Pierre.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one for import...  free and a few snips of code...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/210749/

I haven't tried yet, but will be soon.

You can still access these old links via the internet archive
https://web.archive.org/web/20120420180232/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/210749

Comment: This one actually ended up working great.  Much easier to use than most of Magento. :)

Comment: Link to threads in magento forum aren't working, we don't know the name of the extension. Answer is totally useless now.