# magento - migrate sales tables

Tags: database, magento, transfer

I need to transfer sales tables form an old magento database to a new one

How can i do that without deleting the records from the new database and which are the sales tables

Answer (score 2):

Given how complex Magento's schema is, I would advise against directly writing into the database. If you still want to do it there is this [article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-quote-order-invoice-workflow/) that might help you understand the process as well as all the tables involved. Generally speaking the tables are prefixed with 'sales_'.

Since Magento's core import/export functionality is limited to Products and Customers, your best option is probably to look for an extension that will do this, or write your own. Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673529/magento-order-import-export) on SO that is related to this, providing a link to some paid extensions that do this.

Comment: And how could you just migrate the sales? Given that the sales id's might be in conflict (old vs new)?

Comment: What do you mean by sales? Do you mean orders? Given that a sale has multiple components to it, customer, address, payment, quote, invoice, you need to check a lot of things to do this in direct SQL. Which is why I recommended going with an extension. Given that the entity_id column for Magento is AUTO_INCREMENT, you probably will be fine entering data without an id, and the database will create one. But keeping track of the links of all the old ids and mapping them to new ones in all the entities will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

The sales ID's shouldn't conflict, assuming you do intend to transfer your customers as well since there may also be new that correspond to the sales. To keep this simple and short, which this process really is once you know which tables to export, you do the following:

1. Export all **customer_** and **sales_** tables (these may have a prefix, and will look like something like **yourprefix_customer**.
2. Then, you make sure that the last orders ID is updated in the **eav_entity_store** table, to make sure that Magento created new orders with the correct ID's. You would do the same for the other 3 rows within **eav_entity_store** which are for invoices, shipping and creditmemos.
   Here [more detailed tutorial](http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2013/11/move-magento-sales-customers/) on this topic if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend use a plugin for that situation.

[This](http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Raveinfosys_OrderExporter) **free plugin** worked for me, just install through Magento Connect and then (after refresh cache) you'll see "Exporter" tab on menu with option for import and export.